# Install a BBB js into my pages

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

I have to install this JS script into my theme (paygo) in the bottom so I think it is the footer. I don't know where to start can someone tell me what to do.

```
<!-- BEGIN: BBB AB Seal -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bbb = bbb || [];
    bbb.push(["bbbid", "boston"]);
    bbb.push(["bid", "197111"]);
    bbb.push(["chk", "94177EEAEA"]);
    bbb.push(["pos", "bottom-right"]);
    (function () {
        var scheme = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://");
        var bbb = document.createElement("script");
        bbb.type = "text/javascript";
        bbb.async = true;
        bbb.src = scheme + "seal-boston.bbb.org/badge/badge.min.js";
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(bbb, s);
    })();
</script>
<!-- END: BBB AB Seal -->
```

Comment: you can use body end before

Comment: is that worked for you?